# Entity Provider Selection

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

If i have two entity providers like this

```
MyBean1MessageBodyWriter: @Produces("application/xml") with generic type Object
MyBean2MessageBodyWriter: @Produces("application/xml") with generic type Object
```

Which of entity providers would be used first while serializing `MyBean` class. `MyBean1MessageBodyWriter` or `MyBean2MessageBodyWriter`

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public MyBean getMyBean() {
    return new MyBean("Hello World!", 42);
}
```

I am referring to the example given here  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.

Answer (score 0):

From the JAX-RS 2.0. spec

> 1. Obtain the object that will be mapped to the message entity body. For a return type of `Response` or subclasses, the object is the value of the `entity` property, for other return types it is the returned object.
> 2. Determine the media type of the response
> 3. Select the set of `MessageBodyWriter` providers that support the object and media
>      type of the message entity body.
> 4. Sort the selected `MessageBodyWriter` providers with a primary key of generic type where providers whose generic type is the nearest superclass of the object class are sorted first and a secondary key of media type.
> 5. Iterate through the sorted `MessageBodyWriter` providers and, utilizing the `isWriteable` method of each, choose an `MessageBodyWriter` that supports the object that will be mapped to the entity body.
> 6. If step 5 locates a suitable `MessageBodyWriter` then use its `writeTo` method to map the object to the entity body.
> 7. Otherwise, the server runtime MUST generate a generate an `InternalServerErrorException`, a subclass of `WebApplicationException` with its status set to 500, and no entity  and the client runtime MUST generate a `ProcessingException`.

So it seems like your concerns falls into number 5. The `isWritable` methods should be implemented to disambiguate the two writers. It still after this point, it can't be determined, I am not sure what happens next. You *should* try to separate the ambiguity if you can.

Also I am not certain, by looking at the names of the writers, if both of them are to write `MyBean` types. If that's the case, it seems like a problem. If not, then you could simply check in the `isWritable` if the `Class` argument equals the `MyBean.class`

```
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                           Annotation annotations[], MediaType mediaType) {
    return type == MyBean.class;
}
```